# How to create a delta object that only has fields that changed?

Tags: java, scala, delta

I have to write a common utility class that does following:

Input: 2 objects of the same class - old and new

Output: 1 object of the same class as Inputs, with only the fields that change - delta

Not sure if there is any existing framework out there. I would prefer to use Scala, but even Java is ok.

Comment: "Output: 1 object of the same class as Inputs, with only the fields that change." Can you explain that a little more?

Comment: Sure. Lets say this util is called using person1 and person2 objects of class Person. The output should be deltaPerson, also of class Person (not Object).

Comment: @Roy I'm still as lost as gurung. How could the "delta" be of the same class? And what, exactly, is that delta?

Comment: I'll take one last shot at it: Lets say this util is called using newPerson and oldPerson objects of class Person. The output should be person, also of class Person. The output person should only have fields/attributes populated from newPerson that are different than oldPerson.

Comment: For a `class Person (val age: Int, val name: String, val children: List[Person])`, would that mean to step into the list of children, and only report different children (deep diff), or would we do a flat diff, and just report a different list? Second question: Given a diffPerson between Person a and b, where b has no children. The diffPerson will have no Children too, no matter what Person a has. Is that intendet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the objects are beans, then you can use the [java.beans API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/package-summary.html).  It lets you query what the fields of the bean are, via [Introspector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html#getBeanInfo%28java.lang.Class,%20int%29).  It would be up to you to iterate over all the fields of objA and objB, comparing values, and setting values on objRes.  Also, the class type would have to have a default constructor.